# BI Publisher with Complex Report

Tags: bi-publisher

I have a report with the following metrix:

`Item`, `Total item quantity in month`, `Total item quantity in previous week`, `Total item quantity in 2 previous weeks`, `Total item quantity in 3 previous weeks`

I write this matrix in a single query but it is very complex and take time to execute.

So is there any better solution?

Answer (score 0):

Grouping and filtering in XSLT takes more time and memory than SQL filtering. Oracle recommends doing these kind of complex operations within the data mode (SQL in your case) before printing them in the report.

You should be able to tune your SQL for peformance. Maybe you can ask a DBA for help, or post the SQL under the oracle dba tag here.